# What is the proper way to handle 'parent' transforms when calculating world space?

Tags: c#, transform, game-engine

I've been working on developing a simple 2D game engine, and I've stumbled onto a small problem, I have hierarchy relationships almost working (it works as long as the parent has no rotation), as soon as I add rotation to the parent object however, every child object rotates/moves in a way that does not maintain object cohesion, I assume the problem is in my Transform component.

```cs
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using System.Collections;

namespace Aurora;

/// <summary>
///     Represents the transformation of a game object in the scene.
/// </summary>
public class Transform : Component, IEnumerable<Transform>
{
    #region Fields

    [SerializeField] private readonly List<Transform> m_Children = new();
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 m_LocalPosition = Vector2.Zero;
    [SerializeField] private float m_LocalRotation;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 m_LocalScale = Vector2.One;
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_Parent;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the number of child transforms attached to this transform.
    /// </summary>
    public int ChildCount
    {
        get { return m_Children.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the child transform at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="childIndex">The index of the child transform to retrieve.</param>
    /// <returns>The child transform at the specified index.</returns>
    public Transform this[int childIndex]
    {
        get { return m_Children[childIndex]; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the local position of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 LocalPosition
    {
        get { return m_LocalPosition; }
        set { m_LocalPosition = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the local rotation of the transform in degrees.
    /// </summary>
    public float LocalRotation
    {
        get { return MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(m_LocalRotation); }
        set { m_LocalRotation = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the local scale of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 LocalScale
    {
        get { return m_LocalScale; }
        set { m_LocalScale = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the parent transform of this transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Transform Parent
    {
        get { return m_Parent; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the world position of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the world position of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 WorldPosition
    {
        get
        {
            if ( m_Parent != null )
            {
                Vector2 parentPosition = m_Parent.WorldPosition;
                float parentRotation = m_Parent.WorldRotation;

                // Rotate the local position by the parent's rotation
                Vector2 rotatedPosition = LocalPosition;
                float angle = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians ( parentRotation );
                float cos = (float) Math.Cos ( angle );
                float sin = (float) Math.Sin ( angle );
                rotatedPosition = new Vector2 (
                    cos * rotatedPosition.X - sin * rotatedPosition.Y,
                    sin * rotatedPosition.X + cos * rotatedPosition.Y
                );

                // Add parent's position to the rotated local position
                return parentPosition + rotatedPosition;
            }
            return LocalPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_Parent != null )
            {
                Vector2 parentPosition = m_Parent.WorldPosition;
                float parentRotation = m_Parent.WorldRotation;

                // Calculate the new local position by taking into account parent's rotation
                Vector2 delta = value - parentPosition;
                float angle = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians ( -parentRotation );
                float cos = (float) Math.Cos ( angle );
                float sin = (float) Math.Sin ( angle );
                LocalPosition = new Vector2 (
                    cos * delta.X - sin * delta.Y,
                    sin * delta.X + cos * delta.Y
                );
            }
            else
            {
                LocalPosition = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the world rotation of the transform in degrees.
    /// </summary>
    public float WorldRotation
    {
        get { return LocalRotation - (m_Parent?.WorldRotation ?? 0); }
        set { LocalRotation = value + (m_Parent?.WorldRotation ?? 0); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the world scale of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 WorldScale
    {
        get { return m_LocalScale * (m_Parent?.WorldScale ?? Vector2.One); }
        set
        {
            m_LocalScale = value / (m_Parent?.WorldScale ?? Vector2.One);

            if (float.IsNaN(m_LocalScale.X))
            {
                m_LocalScale.X = 0;
            }

            if (float.IsNaN(m_LocalScale.Y))
            {
                m_LocalScale.Y = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the list of child transforms attached to this transform.
    /// </summary>
    internal List<Transform> Children
    {
        get { return m_Children; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Clears all child transforms attached to this transform.
    /// </summary>
    public void ClearChildren()
    {
        for (int i = m_Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Transform child = m_Children[i];
            child.GameObject.Destroy();
            m_Children.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns an enumerator that iterates through the child transforms.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An enumerator for the child transforms.</returns>
    public IEnumerator<Transform> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_Children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Sets the parent of this transform.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">The new parent transform.</param>
    /// <param name="worldSpaceStays">Whether to maintain world space position, rotation, and scale.</param>
    public void SetParent(Transform parent, bool worldSpaceStays)
    {
        if (worldSpaceStays)
        {
            Vector2 position = WorldPosition;
            float rotation = WorldRotation;
            Vector2 scale = WorldScale;

            m_Parent = parent;
            parent?.m_Children.Add(this);

            if (parent != null)
            {
                if (Scene.IsRegistered(GameObject))
                {
                    Scene.UnRegister(GameObject);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Scene.IsRegistered(GameObject))
                {
                    Scene.Register(GameObject);
                }
            }

            WorldPosition = position;
            WorldRotation = rotation;
            WorldScale = scale;
        }
        else
        {
            m_Parent = parent;
            parent?.m_Children.Add(this);

            if (parent != null)
            {
                if (Scene.IsRegistered(GameObject))
                {
                    Scene.UnRegister(GameObject);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Scene.IsRegistered(GameObject))
                {
                    Scene.Register(GameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns an enumerator that iterates through the child transforms.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An enumerator for the child transforms.</returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your Transform into a matrix. For example [System.Numerics.Matrix3x2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix3x2?view=net-7.0), but there are plenty of alternatives. Matrices have the huge advantage of allowing multiplication to combine them. Therefore giving an easy way to combine multiple transforms. So you should have properties something like this:

```
public Matrix3x2 Local => 
    Matrix3x2.CreateScale(m_LocalScale) *
    Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(m_LocalRotation)*
    Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(m_LocalPosition );

public Matrix3x2  Global => (m_Parent?.Global ?? Matrix3x2.Identity)  * Local;
```

Note that I may have messed up the multiplication order. I cannot remember if system.Numerics follows the conventional order or not. If things does not work, try reversing the order.

This should also avoid all the math for computing world position etc. You should be able to use the matrix directly to render things. If you want to get the world position, just multiply a zero-vector with the global matrix.

I would also consider adding a center vector to specify the point to scale around. And an Angle struct to avoid any confusion about radians/degrees.

Comment: A couple of points. The first is I'm not using System.Numerics for my vectors or matrices, I'm using the OpenTK types, the Matrix3x2 doesn't have a CreateTranslation method, the second is since these matrices aren't square I can't just multiply 3x2 matrices together

Comment: @RWolfe To be honest, OpenTKs matrix classes does not seem well suited for 2D graphics. You could always use a Matrix3, but you would probably need to write your own extension methods to make it simpler to use for 2D graphics. The System.Numerics.Matrix3x2 can be multiplied just fine. The bottom row is implicit, since there is rarely any need for perspective transforms in 2D. An alternative would be to use System.Numerics, and convert to OpenTK types for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer posted by JonasH did not solve my issue, it did point me in the right direction, the correct solution was to use a 3x3 matrix like so

```cs
internal Matrix3 Local
    {
        get
        {
            float cos = MathF.Cos(m_LocalRotation);
            float sin = MathF.Sin(m_LocalRotation);

            Matrix3 local = new()
            {
                M11 = cos * m_LocalScale.X,
                M21 = sin * m_LocalScale.X,
                M12 = -sin * m_LocalScale.Y,
                M22 = cos * m_LocalScale.Y,
                M31 = m_LocalPosition.X,
                M32 = m_LocalPosition.Y,
                M33 = 1.0f
            };

            return local;
        }

        set
        {
            m_LocalPosition.X = value.M31;
            m_LocalPosition.Y = value.M32;

            // Update scale
            m_LocalScale.X = new Vector2(value.M11, value.M21).Length;
            m_LocalScale.Y = new Vector2(value.M12, value.M22).Length;

            float normM11 = value.M11 / m_LocalScale.X;
            float normM21 = value.M21 / m_LocalScale.X;
            m_LocalRotation = MathF.Atan2(normM21, normM11);
        }
    }

    internal Matrix3 Global
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Parent != null)
            {
                return Local * m_Parent.Global;
            }

            return Local;
        }

        set { Local = m_Parent != null ? value * m_Parent.Global.Inverted() : value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the local position of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 LocalPosition
    {
        get { return m_LocalPosition; }
        set { m_LocalPosition = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the local rotation of the transform in degrees.
    /// </summary>
    public float LocalRotation
    {
        get { return MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(m_LocalRotation); }

        set { m_LocalRotation = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the local scale of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 LocalScale
    {
        get { return m_LocalScale; }
        set { m_LocalScale = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the world position of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 WorldPosition
    {
        get
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            return new Vector2(global.M31, global.M32);
        }

        set
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            global.M31 = value.X;
            global.M32 = value.Y;
            Global = global;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the world rotation of the transform in degrees.
    /// </summary>
    public float WorldRotation
    {
        get
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            float sx = new Vector2(global.M11, global.M21).Length;
            float sy = new Vector2(global.M12, global.M22).Length;

            float normM11 = global.M11 / sx;
            float normM21 = global.M21 / sy;

            float angle = MathF.Atan2(normM21, normM11);
            return MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(angle);
        }

        set
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            float sx = new Vector2(global.M11, global.M21).Length;
            float sy = new Vector2(global.M12, global.M22).Length;

            float angle = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(value);
            float cos = MathF.Cos(angle);
            float sin = MathF.Sin(angle);

            global.M11 = cos * sx;
            global.M21 = sin * sx;
            global.M12 = -sin * sy;
            global.M22 = cos * sy;
            Global = global;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the world scale of the transform.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2 WorldScale
    {
        get
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            float sx = new Vector2(global.M11, global.M21).Length;
            float sy = new Vector2(global.M12, global.M22).Length;
            return new Vector2(sx, sy);
        }

        set
        {
            Matrix3 global = Global;
            float rotationAngle = LocalRotation; // Store the current rotation

            // Set the scale, preserving the current rotation
            global.M11 = value.X * MathF.Cos(rotationAngle);
            global.M21 = value.X * MathF.Sin(rotationAngle);
            global.M12 = value.Y * -MathF.Sin(rotationAngle);
            global.M22 = value.Y * MathF.Cos(rotationAngle);

            Global = global;
        }
    }
```